# Convert subscription to string

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have http method that returns one user, this is how it looks when console logged this.usersService.getOneUser().subscribe(data => { console.log(data) });:

```
email: "user2@gmail.com"
id: "1"
phoneNumber: "23421234"
userName: "user2"
```

Now I have to assign received values to a new array object. I try this code:

```
    this.users = new Array(1).fill({}).map((_, index) => {
      return <User>{

        userName: this.usersService.getOneUser().subscribe(data => {JSON.stringify(data.userName)})

      };
    });
```

Tried converting to JSON format, not working. I can add an user if I type values manually, the question is how can I fill it from the data in http request

```
      return <User>{

        email: 'test@mail.com',
        id: '1',
        phoneNumber: '12345',
        userName: 'user'
      };
    });
```

Compiler says userName: Subcription neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.usersService
  .getOneUser()
  .subscribe(data => this.users = [data]);
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.users = new Array(1).fill({}).map((_, index) => {
      return <User>{

        userName: this.usersService.getOneUser().subscribe(data => {JSON.stringify(data.userName)})

      };
    });
```

what may happen is that the call to the `getOneUser()` may not have been finished because it's an asynchronous call so the `Array.fill(..` may be finished executing  before actually getting the user